# How to scrape data properly in Python and BS4?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is the desired output. A CSV file with 2 rows:

```
1639, 06/05/17, 08,09,16,26,37,50
1639, 06/05/17, 13,28,32,33,37,38
```

Today, I have only this, but using VBA Excel code to clean/organize the data:

```
08,09,16,26,37,50
13,28,32,33,37,38
```

[print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rxce.png)

In the first row '1639, 06/05/17' comes from `Resultado <span>Concurso 1639 (06/05/2017)</span>` and '08,09,16,26,37,50' comes from the tag provided below:

```
<ul class="numbers dupla-sena">
<h6>1º sorteio</ <h6>1º sorteio</h6>
<li>08</li><li>09</li><li>16</li><li>26</li><li>37</li><li>50</li>    
</ul>
```

In the second row we can probably copy '1639, 06/05/17' from row 1 and '13,28,32,33,37,38' comes from another tag:

```
<ul class="numbers dupla-sena">
<h6>2º sorteio</h6>
<li>13</li><li>28</li><li>32</li><li>33</li><li>37</li><li>38</li>
</ul>
```

Below is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup 

url = 'http://loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias/landing/duplasena/'

r = requests.get(url)
ltr = soup(r.text, "xml")
ltr.findAll("div",{"class":"content-section section-text with-box no-margin-bottom"})

filename = "ds_1640.csv"
f=open(filename,"w")
```

Using the command below I think I can get ALL that I want, but I don't know how to extract the data the way I need:

```
ltr.findAll("div",{"class":"content-section section-text with-box no-margin-bottom"})
```

So, I tried another way to capture the values from '1º sorteio da dupla-sena'

```
print('-----------------dupla-sena 1º sorteio-----------------------------')
d1 = ltr.findAll("ul",{"class":"numbers dupla-sena"})[0].text.strip()
print(ltr.findAll("ul",{"class":"numbers dupla-sena"})[0].text.strip())
```

Output 1

```
1º sorteio
080916263750
```

To separate the two digit numbers

```
d1 = '0'+ d1 if len(d1)%2 else d1    
gi = [iter(d1)]*2   
r = [''.join(dz1) for dz1 in zip(*gi)]
d3=",".join(r)
```

As a result

```
08,09,16,26,37,50
```

The same goes for the second extraction

```
print('-----------------dupla-sena 2º sorteio-----------------------------')
dd1 = ltr.findAll("ul",{"class":"numbers dupla-sena"})[1].text.strip()
print(ltr.findAll("ul",{"class":"numbers dupla-sena"})[1].text.strip())
```

Output 2

```
2º sorteio
132832333738
```

To separate the two digit numbers

```
dd1 = '0'+ dd1 if len(dd1)%2 else dd1    
gi = [iter(dd1)]*2    
r1 = [''.join(ddz1) for ddz1 in zip(*gi)]    
dd3=",".join(r1)
```

Then we have

```
13,28,32,33,37,38
```

Saving the data to a csv file

```
f.write(d3 + ',' + dd3 +'\n')
f.close()
```

output: a csv file in current directory:

```
01,º ,so,rt,ei,o
,08,09,16,26,37,50,02,º ,so,rt,ei,o
,13,28,32,33,37,38
```

I can use the above method/output, but I have to use VBA excel either to handle this messy data, but I trying to avoid using vba code. Actualy I'm more interested in learning Python and use more and more this powerful Tool.
With this solution I only achieve one part that I want, which is:

```
08,09,16,26,37,50
13,28,32,33,37,38
```

But, as we know, the output desired is:

```
1639, 06/05/17, 08,09,16,26,37,50
1639, 06/05/17, 13,28,32,33,37,38
```

I'm using Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:), Jupyter notebook, in MAC OS X Yosemite(10.10.5).

How can I achieve that? I don't know how can I extract '1639, 06/05/17' and put it in a csv file, Is there a better way to extract the six numbers (08,09,16,26,37,50 and 13,28,32,33,37,38) and do not use the code below and do not use vba?

to separate the two digit numbers:

```
d1 = '0'+ d1 if len(d1)%2 else d1
gi = [iter(d1)]*2
r = [''.join(dz1) for dz1 in zip(*gi)]
```

## UPDATED QUESTION

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
import re
import csv

url = 'http://loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias/landing/duplasena/'

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")  ## "lxml" to avoid the warning

pat = re.compile(r'(?i)(?<=concurso)\s*(?P<concurso>\d+)\s*\((?P<data>.+?)(?=\))')
concurso_e_data = soup.find(id='resultados').h2.span.text
match = pat.search(concurso_e_data)


# first I would do the above part differently seeing as how you want the end data to look
if match:
    concurso, data = match.groups()
    nums = soup.find_all("ul", {"class": "numbers dupla-sena"})
    num_headers = (','.join(['numero%d']*6) % tuple(range(1,7))).split(',')
    # unpack numheaders into field names
    field_names = ['sena', 'data', *num_headers]
    # above gives you this
    # field_names = [
    #    'sena',               ## I've changed "seria"for "sena"
    #    'data',
    #    'numero1',
    #    'numero2',
    #    'numero3',
    #    'numero4',
    #    'numero5',
    #    'numero6',
    # ]
    
    
rows = []
# then add the numbers
# nums is all the `ul` list elements contains the drawing numbers
for group in nums:
    # start each row with the shared concurso, data elements
    row = [concurso, data]
    # for each `ul` get all the `li` elements containing the individual number
    for num in group.findAll('li'):
        # add each number
        row.append(int(num.text))
    # get [('sena', '1234'), ('data', '12/13'2017'),...]
    row_title_value_pairs = zip(field_names, row)
    # turn into dict {'sena': '1234', 'data': '12/13/2017', ...}
    row_dict = dict(row_title_value_pairs)
    rows.append(row_dict)
    
    
    # so now rows looks like: [{
    #   'sena': '1234', 
    #   'data': '12/13/2017', 
    #   'numero1': 1, 
    #   'numero2': 2, 
    #   'numero3': 3, 
    #   'numero4': 4, 
    #   'numero5': 5, 
    #   'numero6': 6
    #   }, ...]



    with open('file_v5.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(
            csvfile,
            fieldnames=field_names,
            dialect='excel',
            extrasaction='ignore', # drop extra fields if not in field_names not necessary but just in case
            quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC  # quote anything thats not a number, again just in case
        )
        csv_writer.writeheader()
        for row in rows:
            csv_writer.writerow(row_dict)
```

Output

```
# "sena","data","numero1","numero2","numero3","numero4","numero5","numero6"
# "1641","11/05/2017",1,5,15,28,30,43
# "1641","11/05/2017",1,5,15,28,30,43  #This comes from 1. drawing and not 
from the corcect one (2.)
```

## UPDATED QUESTION 2

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
import re
import csv

url = 'http://loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias/landing/duplasena/'

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")  ## "lxml" to avoid the warning

pat = re.compile(r'(?i)(?<=concurso)\s*(?P<concurso>\d+)\s*\((?P<data>.+?)(?=\))')
concurso_e_data = soup.find(id='resultados').h2.span.text
match = pat.search(concurso_e_data)

# everything should be indented under this block since 
# if there is no match then none of the below code should run
if match:  
    concurso, data = match.groups()
    nums = soup.find_all("ul", {"class": "numbers dupla-sena"})
    num_headers = (','.join(['numero%d']*6) % tuple(range(1,7))).split(',')
    field_names = ['sena', 'data', *num_headers]

    # PROBLEM 1
    # all this should be indented into the `if match:` block above
    # none of this should run if there is no match
    # you cannot build the rows without the match for sena and data
    # Let's add some print statements to see whats going on
    rows = []
    for group in nums:
        # here each group is a full `sena` row from the site
        print('Pulling sena: ', group.text)
        row = [concurso, data]
        print('Adding concurso + data to row: ', row)
        for num in group.findAll('li'):
            row.append(int(num.text))
            print('Adding {} to row.'.format(num))
        print('Row complete: ', row)
        row_title_value_pairs = zip(field_names, row)
        print('Transform row to header, value pairs: ', row_title_value_pairs)
        row_dict = dict(row_title_value_pairs)
        print('Row dictionary: ', row_dict)
        rows.append(row_dict)
        print('Rows: ', rows)

    # PROBLEM 2
    # It would seem that you've confused this section when switching
    # out the original list comprehension with the more explicit 
    # for loop in building the rows.
    
# The below block should be indented to this level.
# Still under the `if match:`, but out of the the 
# `for group in nums:` above

    # the below block loops over rows, but you are still building
    # the rows in the for loop
    # you are effectively double looping over the values in `row`

    
    with open('ds_v4_copy5.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(
        csvfile,
        fieldnames=field_names,
        dialect='excel',
        extrasaction='ignore', # drop extra fields if not in field_names not necessary but just in case
        quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC  # quote anything thats not a number, again just in case
        )
        csv_writer.writeheader()
        # this is where you are looping extra because this block is in the `for` loop mentioned in my above notes
        #for row in rows:  ### I tried here to avoid the looping extra
            #print('Adding row to CSV: ', row)
        csv_writer.writerow(row_dict)
```

I think I followed your instructions. But we got this so far:

```
"sena","data","numero1","numero2","numero3","numero4","numero5","numero6"
"1643","16/05/2017",3,4,9,19,21,26  #which is "1º sorteio"
```

Still missing "2º sorteio". I know I'm doing something wrong, because both "1º sorteio" and "2º sorteio" are in:

```
print(rows[0]) --> {'sena': '1643', 'data': '16/05/2017', 'numero1': 1, 'numero2': 21, 'numero3': 22, 'numero4': 43, 'numero5': 47, 'numero6': 50} 

 print(rows[1]) --> {'sena': '1643', 'data': '16/05/2017', 'numero1': 3, 'numero2': 4, 'numero3': 9, 'numero4': 19, 'numero5': 21, 'numero6': 26}
```

But, when I try to store the content of row_dict in csv (only row[0] appears in row_dict. I'm trying to figure out how to include the missing one. Maybe I'm wrong, but I presume that both "1º sorteio" and "2º sorteio" should be included in row_dict, but the code does not confirm it (it`s a guess) when we see this:

```
print(row_dict)
{'sena': '1643', 'data': '16/05/2017', 'numero1': 3, 'numero2': 4, 'numero3': 9, 'numero4': 19, 'numero5': 21, 'numero6': 26}
```

I can't see what I'm doing wrong. I know it's taking to much time this answer, but I'm learning a lot with you in this process. And already using several tools that I learn with you (re, concepts, dict, zip).

Comment: added solution with explanation

Comment: the issue here is that you've copied and pasted different parts of the code without taking the time to understand what it does. I have tried to mark each line with a description of what it does, but if you do not take the time to read it then these mistakes will happen. Check my second update...

Comment: Well done to you both for the perseverance to get the required result, good work. However, there are probably too many questions stuffed into the one post here, and it is a Stack Exchange principle to keep questions a bit more simple than this. First of all Fabio, Verbal_Kint has been very kind in his/her answer, but most answerers may ask you (quite correctly) to start a new question.

Comment: The main reason for this is that a single question may be useful to future readers; complex issues can be broken up, so that new readers do not have to fully grok the previous stage to understand the current one. However, a multi-stage set of problems in the same question becomes rather unique to the asker, and so it may not have as much future applicability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am not that familiar with beautiful soup, I usually use lxml, that being said...

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)  # <-- edit showing how i assigned soup
pat = re.compile(r'(?i)(?<=concurso)\s*(?P<concurso>\d+)\s*\((?P<data>.+?)(?=\))')
concurso_e_data = soup.find(id='resultados').h2.span.text
match = pat.search(concurso_e_data)
if match:
    concurso, data = match.groups()
    nums = soup.find_all("ul", {"class": "numbers dupla-sena"})
    numeros = []
    for i in nums:
        numeros.append(','.join(j.text for j in i.findAll('li')))
    rows = []
    for n in numeros:
        rows.append(','.join([concurso, data, n]))

print(rows)
['1639,06/05/2017,08,09,16,26,37,50', '1639,06/05/2017,13,28,32,33,37,38']
```

While this is the format you asked for, isn't using comas (the column delimiter) in the number groups a bad idea. You should either delimit with another character or separate the numbers with a space.

### UPDATE 1:

Writing in the comments section isn't the best way to do this so... Assuming the format you really want is 8 rows as follows `(seria, data, num1, num2, ... num6)` where `seria` and `data` are strings and the numbers are `int`s:

```
# first I would do the above part differently seeing as how you want the end data to look
...
if match:
    concurso, data = match.groups()
    nums = soup.find_all("ul", {"class": "numbers dupla-sena"})
    num_headers = (','.join(['numero%d']*6) % tuple(range(1,7))).split(',')
    # unpack numheaders into field names
    field_names = ['seria', 'data', *num_headers]
    # above gives you this
    # field_names = [
    #    'seria',
    #    'data',
    #    'numero1',
    #    'numero2',
    #    'numero3',
    #    'numero4',
    #    'numero5',
    #    'numero6',
    # ]
    rows = [
        dict(zip(
            field_names, 
            [concurso, data, *[int(num.text) for num in group.findAll('li')]]
        )) 
        for group in nums]
    # so now rows looks like: [{
    #   'seria': '1234', 
    #   'data': '12/13/2017', 
    #   'numero1': 1, 
    #   'numero2': 2, 
    #   'numero3': 3, 
    #   'numero4': 4, 
    #   'numero5': 5, 
    #   'numero6': 6
    #   }, ...]
    with open('file.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(
            csvfile,
            fieldnames=field_names,
            dialect='excel',
            extrasaction='ignore', # drop extra fields if not in field_names not necessary but just in case
            quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC  # quote anything thats not a number, again just in case
        )
        csv_writer.writeheader()
        for row in rows:
            csv_writer.writerow(row_dict)
```

This part is a bit cluttered:

```
rows = [
    dict(zip(
        field_names, 
        [concurso, data, *[int(num.text) for num in group.findAll('li')]
    )) 
    for group in nums]
```

So let me write it another way:

```
rows = []
# then add the numbers
# nums is all the `ul` list elements contains the drawing numbers
for group in nums:
    # start each row with the shared concurso, data elements
    row = [concurso, data]
    # for each `ul` get all the `li` elements containing the individual number
    for num in group.findAll('li'):
        # add each number
        row.append(int(num.text))
    # get [('seria', '1234'), ('data', '12/13'2017'),...]
    row_title_value_pairs = zip(field_names, row)
    # turn into dict {'seria': '1234', 'data': '12/13/2017', ...}
    row_dict = dict(row_title_value_pairs)
    rows.append(row_dict)
    # or just write the csv here instead of appending to rows and re-looping over the values
    ...
```

#### UPDATE 2:

The one thing I want you to learn from this is to use `print` statements while learning so you can understand what the code does. I will not make the corrections but I will point them out and add the `print` statements in every location where some significant change happens...

```
match = pat.search(concurso_e_data)


# everything should be indented under this block since 
# if there is no match then none of the below code should run
if match:  
    concurso, data = match.groups()
    nums = soup.find_all("ul", {"class": "numbers dupla-sena"})
    num_headers = (','.join(['numero%d']*6) % tuple(range(1,7))).split(',')
    field_names = ['sena', 'data', *num_headers]

# PROBLEM 1
# all this should be indented into the `if match:` block above
# none of this should run if there is no match
# you cannot build the rows without the match for sena and data
# Let's add some print statements to see whats going on
rows = []
for group in nums:
    # here each group is a full `sena` row from the site
    print('Pulling sena: ', group.text)
    row = [concurso, data]
    print('Adding concurso + data to row: ', row)
    for num in group.findAll('li'):
        row.append(int(num.text))
        print('Adding {} to row.'.format(num))
    print('Row complete: ', row)
    row_title_value_pairs = zip(field_names, row)
    print('Transform row to header, value pairs: ', row_title_value_pairs)
    row_dict = dict(row_title_value_pairs)
    print('Row dictionary: ', row_dict)
    rows.append(row_dict)
    print('Rows: ', rows)

    # PROBLEM 2
    # It would seem that you've confused this section when switching
    # out the original list comprehension with the more explicit 
    # for loop in building the rows.
# The below block should be indented to this level.
# Still under the `if match:`, but out of the the 
# `for group in nums:` above

    # the below block loops over rows, but you are still building
    # the rows in the for loop
    # you are effectively double looping over the values in `row`
    with open('file_v5.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(
            csvfile,
            fieldnames=field_names,
            dialect='excel',
            extrasaction='ignore', # drop extra fields if not in field_names not necessary but just in case
            quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC  # quote anything thats not a number, again just in case
        )
        csv_writer.writeheader()
        # this is where you are looping extra because this block is in the `for` loop mentioned in my above notes
        for row in rows:
            print('Adding row to CSV: ', row)
            csv_writer.writerow(row_dict)
```

Run this and see what the print statements show you. But read the notes as well because there is something that will cause an error if sena, data dont match.

HINT: make the indent and then add `else: print('No sena, data match!')` under the `if match:` block at the very end... But run this first and check the what it prints.

Comment: Hi @Verbal_Kint, thanks for your help! I tried and got this message:
TypeError: find() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: @fabio Voce nao pode simplesmente me dar o erro sem o traceback. Mas, eu acho que sei qual e o problema. Meu variable "soup" e sua "soup" sao definidas diferente. Eu mudei a primeira linha do meu code.

Comment: boa recomendação!! Deu certo, consegui chegar na solução parcial. Como exportar adequadamente?  Usei esse metodo abaixo e ele transporta para o csv mas ele ignora o formato desejado (todos os dados em 2 linhas e 8 colunas: concurso-1coluna, data do sorteio-1coluna e resultado da extracao (6 dezenas - 6 colunas):
file = 'ds_stack.csv'
with open(file,'a') as f:
   writer = csv.writer(f)
   writer.writerow(rows)

Comment: foi falha minha na declaracao do problema, talvez nao tenha sido claro quanto a necessidade de deixar os dados em duas linhas e 6 colunas. Tentei concatenar, mas nao se pode (str to list). Veja o traceback:filename = "ds_stack_2.csv"
f=open(filename,"w")
f.write(rows+'\n')
f.close() 

TypeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-a2371cd1198b> in <module>()
      1 filename = "ds_stack_2.csv"
      2 f=open(filename,"w")
----> 3 f.write(rows+'\n')
      4 f.close()
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Comment: @fabio nao precisa o '\n':  `f.write(rows+'\n')` --> `f.write(rows)`. Mais porque nao esta usando `csvwriter`? O problma e qui rows e tipo list e '\n' e tipo string

Comment: e tambien se precisa 8 colunas, tira todos os espaços: `'1639, 06/05/2017, 08,09,16,26,37,50'` --> `'1639,06/05/2017,08,09,16,26,37,50'`

Comment: Hi @Verbal_Kint, consegui chegar ate aqui (duas primeiras colunas da primeira linha) com o que temos ateh agora filename = "ds_stack_3.csv"
f=open(filename,"w")
f.write(concurso+ ';' + data +'\n')
f.close()
O desafio agora e continuar com a variable nums. Alguma sugestao?

Comment: @fabio Nao sei o que e os variables? whats `data`? is `concurso` a string?
 show the code and please format it by surround code with this char --> `. 
   traceback also...

Comment: I was talking about nums, like -->print(nums[0]) --><ul class="numbers dupla-sena"><h6>1º sorteio</h6><li>10</li><li>12</li><li>15</li><li>24</li><li>25</li><li>48</li></ul>. But I tried another way, take a look.

Comment: -->file = 'ds_1641.csv'-->with open(file,'a') as f:-->writer = csv.writer(f) 
 -->writer.writerow(rows[0]) -->writer.writerow(rows[1]). I used this and got -->1,6,4,0,",", ,0,9,/,0,5,/,2,0,1,7,",", ,1,0,",",1,2,",",1,5,",",2,4,",",2,5,",",4,8
-->1,6,4,0,",", ,0,9,/,0,5,/,2,0,1,7,",", ,0,3,",",0,9,",",2,3,",",3,2,",",3,4,",",5,0. Inside excel, I`ve cleaned up and formatting (still using VBA) in 2 rows and 8 columns. I don`t know how to organize the results inside python the way I need. Do you have a better and final approach than mine? I think we're closer to the desired output.

Comment: Wowwww @Verbal_Kint!! Thank you so much! Amazing and dedicated solution!! I'll study it tomorrow! Best regards!!

Comment: @fabio please accept the answer if you've found it useful

Comment: I followed the exact proposed solution and something strange happened. When I save the csv file the results it shows: -->"sena","data","numero1","numero2","numero3","numero4","numero5","numero6"-->"1641","11/05/2017",1,5,15,28,30,43 -->"1641","11/05/2017",1,5,15,28,30,43. But when I -->print(rows[0]) whe'll have -->{'sena': '1641', 'data': '11/05/2017', 'numero1': 3, 'numero2': 30, 'numero3': 32, 'numero4': 34, 'numero5': 36, 'numero6': 42} and  -->print(rows[1]) -->{'sena': '1641', 'data': '11/05/2017', 'numero1': 1, 'numero2': 5, 'numero3': 15, 'numero4': 28, 'numero5': 30, 'numero6': 43}.

Comment: print(rows[0]) and print(rows[1]) shows the exact and correct extraction from the drawings! But, saving to csv files, we'll have both drawings(1 and 2) duplicated by the first drawing. It's a weird behavior, maybe I did something wrong in the process. Any idea?  note: I used the another way you proposed, that is less "cluttered", using your words!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do this update. I looked for a solution and I didn't find it. Actually, I found this [link]https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers but, unfortunatelly, this doesn't provide the solution to update part of the question.

Comment: @fabio It means edit your question and include the extra information at the bottom so it isnt cluttered into this small comments section

Comment: Great explanations @Verbal_KInt! I've learned a lot so far!! I'm using, for example, dict, zip, formatting questions, the "modus operandi" here in another cases! I'll study your code thoroughly for the next 3 days! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

With your help @Verbal_Kint, we got here! The output the way I need! I've changed the output to:

```
sena;data;numero1;numero2;numero3;numero4;numero5;numero6
1644;18/05/2017;4;6;31;39;47;49
1644;18/05/2017;20;37;44;45;46;50
```

So, following their concern about "," and ";" in Excel, I decide to change `","` for `";"` to open column in Excel without any issue.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
import re
import csv

url = 'http://loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias/landing/duplasena/'

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")  ## "lxml" to avoid the warning

pat = re.compile(r'(?i)(?<=concurso)\s*(?P<concurso>\d+)\s*\((?P<data>.+?)(?=\))')
concurso_e_data = soup.find(id='resultados').h2.span.text
match = pat.search(concurso_e_data)

if match:  
    concurso, data = match.groups()
    nums = soup.find_all("ul", {"class": "numbers dupla-sena"})
    num_headers = (','.join(['numero%d']*6) % tuple(range(1,7))).split(',')
    field_names = ['sena', 'data', *num_headers]

    rows = []
    for group in nums:
        row = [concurso, data]
        for num in group.findAll('li'):
            row.append(int(num.text))
        row_title_value_pairs = zip(field_names, row)
        row_dict = dict(row_title_value_pairs)
        rows.append(row_dict)

    with open('ds_v10.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(
        csvfile,
        fieldnames=field_names,             
        dialect='excel',       
            delimiter = ';',  #to handle column issue in excel!
        )
        csv_writer.writeheader()
        csv_writer.writerow(rows[0])
        csv_writer.writerow(rows[1])
```

Comment: Thanks @halfer for your help! Much better now!